# Unprocessable Entity when trying to upload file via Ajax

Tags: php, laravel, iis-10

I just moved my local code over to live server. Everything is working but when I try to upload an image on the live server I get "Unprocessable Entity" error. The file upload works perfectly on my local server. I am using Windows server with IIS and PHP 7.2 and my project is using laravel 5.5

I have already tried given full control permissions to IUSER and IIS_IUSRS. I also tried updating the php.ini file (file_uploads = On, upload_max_filesize = 20M,post_max_size = 20M)

My Form

```
<form class='form-inline' id='edit-property-image' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' id='property' value='$id' name='property'>
    <input type='file' class='custom-file-input' id='propertyImage' name='propertyImage' onchange='propertyImageChange(this)'>
    <a href='javascript:updatePropertyImage($id)' class='btn btn-primary'>Update Image</a>
</form>
```

Ajax Method

```
function updatePropertyImage(id) 
{
    $.ajax({
        data:new FormData($("#edit-property-image")[0]),
        async:false,
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
        url: '/property/updateImage', // This is the url we gave in the route
        success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            if(response.response == "success") {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                propertyDetails(id);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller
$id = $request->input('property');

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'propertyImage' => 'image|max:1999|required'
    ]);

    $response = "failed";
    //Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('propertyImage')){
        //Get Filename with extension
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('propertyImage')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get just extension
        $extension = $request->file('propertyImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore = $id.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('propertyImage')->storeAs('public/property_images', $fileNameToStore);

        $property = Property::find($id);
        $property->image_url = $fileNameToStore;
        $property->save();

        $response = "success";
    }

    return response()->json([
        'response' => $response,
    ]);
```

Comment: I think this is due to validation error so, please check laravel validation in browser.Also check file size not greater than 1999 as per 'propertyImage' => 'image|max:1999|required'

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. It was actually because my php.ini file did not specify a default temp folder. Once I added that the file upload worked.